# Add URL parameters after page number in wordpress

Tags: php

I'm using pagination in posts so my URL can look like this when on page 3:

`mysite.com/custom-post-archive/page/3`

That works fine but I want to add parameters after the page number for example:

`mysite.com/custom-post-archive/page/3?param=hello&another=world`

It returns 404/page not found with the URL parameters...

I tried:

```
function my_query_vars( $vars ) {
    $vars[] = 'param';
    $vars[] = 'another';
    return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'my_query_vars' );
```

But still does not work. How can I add parameters (not prettified URL segments) to URLS that have the page URL segments?

Answer (score -1):

Please share your URL. So, I can help you out.

Try with resetting the permalinks.

Go to `Settings > Permalinks` Select **Plain** then **Save**.
Again select **Post Name** then hit **Save**.